# A chrome extension that lets you edit the source code of a page (doesn't have to save)

Tags: web-development, chrome

I often see a demo for some library or other, and I want to try to make a small change. So I have to download the entire page with all dependencies and then make the change there. I'd like to be able to make the change when I view the source code in the browser.

Comment: The built-in developer tools allow you to modify things, can I post that as an answer? If it is not a good solution, please edit your question to explain why, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try [tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/). This extension changes the HTML code of the page with Javascript, when the page loads. This is called DOM manipulation.

Tampermonkey is not really a High-Level HTML editor, though.

For instance this script:
https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/536-imdb-standard-deviation/code

changes this:
`Arithmetic mean = 7.5   Median = 8`

to this`:     Arithmetic mean = 7.5   Median = 8   Standard Deviation = 2.02`

on the IMDB [Ratings page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9495224/ratings?ref_=tt_ov_rt) of 'Black Mirror' movie